# java- ¿ Como usar correctamente PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statements

Resulta que estoy intentando parametrizar una `querie`, al parecer toma los datos pero devuelve un resultado erróneo por ejemplo.

```
Select campo from tabla where nombre ='pepito'
```

*No devuelve nada*

```
select campo from tabla where nombre <>'jose'
**pepito**, juan,horacio
```

devuelve los distintios y lo mismo pasa cuando pongo un menor que, o mayor que (en caso que consulte un campo numerico)

```
str = "SELECT TABLA WHERE ? "+ operador +"?";
PreparedStatement prepstm = null;
Connection conn;
conn = DBConnector.getInstance().conect();
prepstm = conn.prepareStatement(str);
prepstm.setString(1, campo);
prepstm.setString(2, valor);
ResultSet rs = prepstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: De entrada `WHERE ?` no funcionará, ya que los prepared statement no son para reemplazar nombres de columnas o de tabla, son solamente para reemplazar valores.

Comment: ahi lo edito, me olvide de poner todo el string

Comment: eso me dijeron, pero el codigo fuente ya tenia el where ? = ? y funcionaba perfecto

Comment: Aquí : `prepstm.setString(1, columna)`  se ve claramente que quieres usar preparedstatement para setear un nombre de columna. Eso es imposible, porque ps no está diseñado para eso y por lo tanto no funcionará. Los nombres de columna deben ser escritos de forma explícita o a lo sumo, ser pasados en parámetro a un método.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que esa llamada es correcta, asigna a la posición 1 el valor de la variable columna.

Comment: Bueno, pero `where ? = ?` es algo muy ambiguo que puede servir hasta para que te hagan una inyección SQL. No es lo mismo algo como `where ? = ?` si tú le pasas dos valores al statement, que si le pasas un nombre de columna y un valor. O sea, un `ps` te admitiría que le pasas dos números en cada marcador, lo que produciría por ejemplo: `where 1 = 1`, pero no que le pases un nombre de columna y un número: `where columna = 1`... No sé si me explico. En el 1er caso funcionaría, en el 2º no, por la naturaleza misma de `preparedstatement`

Comment: @JDev no es correcta, fíjate como está escrita la consulta: `str = "SELECT TABLA WHERE ? "+ operador +"?"` ¿dónde está el nombre de la columna de esa consulta? Es evidente que el nombre de la columna sería lo que el intenta poner con el primer marcador `?`.  Ese dato no podrá ser pasado **jamás** usando los métodos de `PreparedStatement`. Ni en Java ni en ningún otro lenguaje que yo conozca.

Comment: que quede claro que la consulta me la hace, el codigo entiende que columna quiero, como explique arriba, si yo busco un distinto a pepito, me trae los nombres **distintos a pepito**

Comment: Sugiero que edites tu pregunta poniendo el código **real** que estás usando. Con una consulta escrita así: `SELECT TABLA WHERE ? "+ operador +"?"` es imposible que funcione. Tú no puedes bajo ningún concepto pasar un nombre de columna como parámetro a un `PreparedStatement`. Ni tampoco puedes escribir una consulta válida de este modo: `SELECT TABLA WHERE pepito = pepito`  o `SELECT TABLA WHERE pepito <> pepito`. A esa consulta le falta el **nombre de la columna** y más elementos... La consulta es errónea desde el punto de vista **sintáctico**.